Customize WordPress "Comment-function" or other built-in WordPress function with approval option
The idea: I was asked to recreate this sort of petition but in WordPress.
Basically, the users should be able to add their name (1), their e-mail (2) and upon ticking both check marks (3) that their name will be displayed in a list (4) below.

Usually, I'd say, that's an easy push/pop into an array - however...
Profanity issue:
What I said to the client is that the example is not ideal because there is not check on the names. Users can write whatever derogatory word they want as a name. So, the input name should go through a check-up confirmation first and only after that has been approved, then the name should appear. The e-mail should be added to a list, ideally excel.
WP comment function: My first instinct was, that perhaps I could use the inbuilt comment function of WordPress for that. I remember that comments have to be approved by someone with admin permissions before they appear publicly. So, the user would add their name and e-mail but no actual comment. The comment(name) would then be sent for approval and then after approval, the name would appear in the list below.
Alternative options: I can't think of any other built-in WordPress function that could be subject to "approval" other than comments. I also proposed as a fall-back solution because the launch is pretty soon, that I can set up a simple form, which would capture the "name" and "e-mail" but that the admins would have to type out the names manually and the names would be WordPress "tags".
Question 1: Is it possible to add the comment function to a specific page or is it limited to just "posts"?
Question 2: Other than the comment function of WP, which built-in WordPress function or a plugin might be a more suitable solution?
I'm open to any creative leads/ideas!
